# Redirect for all action controller's

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

There is only one control Home with a bunch of action. It also has a private method bool IsFinish (), which returns the state of the system. At a certain stage (namely when IsFinish start returning *true*) is necessary, what any callable method redirected to public ActionResult Result (). In principle, I do not care where this will Result - in the current controller or the other. Overview all actions forward to it.

How can this be implemented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use an [`action filter`](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) of asp.net mvc to do it. An action filter is an attribute that you can apply to a `controller` `action` -- or an entire `controller` -- that modifies the way in which the action is executed, for sample:

```
public class RedirectFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            // get the home controller in a safe cast
            var homeController = filterContext.Controller as Controller;

            // check if it is home controller and not Result action
            if (homeController != null && filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName != "Result")
            {
                if (homeController.IsFinish())
                {
                    filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                        new RouteValueDictionary 
                        { 
                            { "controller", "Home" }, 
                            { "action", "Result" } 
                        });
                }
            }

            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        }
}
```

And apply it on your controller:

```
[RedirectFilter] // apply to all actions
public class HomeController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Home()
    {
        /* your action's code */
    }

    public ActionResult Home()
    {
        /* your action's code */
    }

    public ActionResult Home()
    {
        /* your action's code */
    }

    public ActionResult Result()
    {        
        return View();
    }
}
```